# Accessing a static variable from different assemblies

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have an ASP.NET application and a Windows Service. I am using Unity as the IoC container. I placed the Composition Root in a seperate class library, because both applications are supposed to use the same DI container.

DI bootstrapper:

```
namespace CompositionRoot {

 public static class DiBootstrapper {

  private static IUnityContainer _container;

  public static IUnityContainer Initialize() {
   return _container ?? (_container = BuildUnityContainer());
  }

  private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer() {
   var container = new UnityContainer();
   container.AddNewExtension<ContainerExtension>();
   return container;
  }

 }

 public class ContainerExtension: UnityContainerExtension {
  protected override void Initialize() {
   var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KSecureEntities"].ConnectionString;
   var sqlCtorParam = new InjectionConstructor(connectionString);
   this.Container.RegisterType < Acquaintance.RSS.IRssRepository, RssRepository > (new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
   this.Container.RegisterType < IRssFeedRepository, RssFeedRepository > (new TransientLifetimeManager(), sqlCtorParam);
   this.Container.RegisterType<IRssTicker, RssTicker>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
   this.Container.RegisterType < RssTickerHub > (new InjectionFactory(RssTickerHub));
   ....
  }

  private static object RssTickerHub(IUnityContainer p) {
   var rssRepository = p.Resolve < IRssFeedRepository > ();
   var rssTicker = p.Resolve < IRssTicker > ();
   var rssTickerHub = new RssTickerHub(rssRepository, rssTicker);
   return rssTickerHub;
  }
 }

}
```

The first project to run Initialize() on the DiBootstrapper is the Windows Service. When the method is run, the _container variable is set.

Afterwards the ASP.NET application runs Initialize() from Application_Start(), but this time the variable is null, and the container gets instantiated again.

How can I share the same container across both projects?

Comment: A static object lives within the scope of a process. You've got two: the service and the web application. Each one will host it's own instance of the container. If you want to access it from a different process, you have to write some kind of IPC-Protocol that performs the actions you need on the instance. First you have to decide where the container should live. Then you have to implement a service to access it there. Last you should call this service in order to access the container from the client. There are many ways of doing this: .NET Remoting, WCF or some high level framework like Zyan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You cannot.

It does not work that way. You have two different processes, the Windows Service and the process your webserver spuns up when your ASP.NET is called. They both load the library assembly, but each loads his own copy into memory. That's how processes work with libraries.

There is no easy solution. You cannot share objects that way. You will need to find another solution. If you don't have singleton lifetimes in your DI container, just having the same configuration for both processes should be enough. if you want to share objects between processes, you might be best served by asking a new question on how to do that *in a specific situation* because there are many ways to achieve a goal without doing it, but we need to know your goal to give such an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have singleton lifetimes in my container. More precisely I have a SignalR hub in the ASP.NET project, and I want the Windows Service to do background work and broadcast server messages to the clients when it finishes.