# Passing dynamic values between projects in the same solution

Tags: c#

I need to pass dynamic values between a winform(c#) project and a webform project in the same solution.
I've added a reference from one project to the other.
I'm able to get the initial values assigned to public static variables, but not dynamic values.

I've tried several related examples from this site (Runtime values, Global Variables).

```
namespace TestWeb_01 // Source Project 
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static string Time_Web = "xxxx";
    public static GlobalVariablesClass globals = new GlobalVariablesClass();

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Time_Web = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        RuntimeValues.Runtime_String1 = "zzzz";
        globals.VariableOne = "www";

        Refresh();
    }
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// Write Time
    {
        Time_Web = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        RuntimeValues.Runtime_String1 = 
 DateTime.Now.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        globals.VariableOne = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        Refresh();
    }
...

using TestWeb_01;// Winform project

namespace FormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Time_Web_lbl.Text = "Initial";
        Runtime_lbl.Text = "Initial";
        Global_lbl.Text = "Initial";
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        Time_Web_lbl.Text = WebForm1.Time_Web;
        Runtime_lbl.Text = RuntimeValues.Runtime_String1;
        Global_lbl.Text = WebForm1.globals.VariableOne;
    }
...
```

I'm only able to get the "xxxx" value in the winform, I get blanks for the Runtime and Global variables, and no daytime value updates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a static variable from different assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906216/accessing-a-static-variable-from-different-assemblies)

Answer (score 0):

If you've used references, then what you're essentially passing is a copy of the **non-runtime** project to the other one, and vice versa. This means that both projects can only access the starting values of the other, and don't look at their memory at runtime.

You cannot get values in different projects during runtime just by using a reference, you need to pass them using either files on your system, or preferably, networking, which can be done through [sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples), [HTTP request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest?view=netframework-4.8) or in some cases [WCF.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf)

Projects produce [completely isolated executables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and cannot peek each other's memory at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Larry, I'm not using DLL references, I've used the reference manager to add a reference in the winforms project to the webforms project. And I get the initial values from the (public static) variables, but not dynamic values.

Comment: @JoeM That is what I'm talking about, the reference manager will simply add a reference to the built project, which is **not running**. There is no way to get variables from a running program's memory just through reference. The reference you're accessing **isn't running.**